# Div heights inside Core Drawer Panel are fixed?

Tags: html, css, polymer, core-elements

I have a set of material design cards that look fine on their own, but when I put them inside a Core Drawer Panel, it looks like div heights are getting fixed. I'm trying to find a solution for the way they're getting compacted vertically.

This is what it looks like outside the Core Drawer Panel:

[image: Material design card]

This is what 3 cards look like inside the Core Drawer Panel (not showing that actual left-hand drawer, but that looks fine):

[image]

Here's a simplified version of my code (polymer imports not displayed):

```
<head>
    <style>
        #mainDiv {
        background-color: transparent;
        overflow: scroll;
        }
        #mainDiv * {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        background: #eee;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 40px;
        margin: 0;
        color: #2E2E3C;
        line-height: 24px;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        }
        #mainDiv * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        }

        #mainDiv *::-moz-selection {
            color: #CFD8DC;
            background: #009688;
        }

        #mainDiv * ::selection {
            color: #CFD8DC;
            background: #009688;
        }

        #mainDiv * ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 10px!important;
            background: #FAFAFA;
        }

        #mainDiv * ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .08);
        }

        #mainDiv * ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        }
        /* End defaults*/

        #mainDiv .card {
            display: block;
            vertical-align: top;
            width: 350px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 10px;
            background: #FFF;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
            color: #272727;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }
        #mainDiv .card .title {
            line-height: 48px;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        #mainDiv .card .content {
            padding: 20px;
            font-weight: 300;
            border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        }
        #mainDiv .card p {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #mainDiv .card .action {
            border-top: 1px solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
            padding: 20px;
        }
        #mainDiv .card a {
            color: #ffab40;
            margin-right: 20px;
            -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
            transition: color 0.3s ease;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #mainDiv .card .image {
            position: relative;
        }
        #mainDiv .card .image img {
            border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #mainDiv .card .image .title {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            color: #FFF;
        }
        #mainDiv .checkBoxSpan {
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <core-drawer-panel>
        <div drawer>    
            <!— bunch of dropdown menus —>
        </div drawer>

        <div main id="mainDiv" layout vertical>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="content">
                    <span class="title">Card title</span>
                    <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="action">
                    <a href='#'>This is a link</a>
                    <a href='#'>This is a link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </core-drawer-panel>
</body>
```

For reference, the material card code is from here: http://materialdesignblog.com/10-material-design-cards-for-web-in-css-html/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same in core-drawer-panel, but in paper-drawer-panel, you will have to use a paper-scroll-header-panel or paper-header-panel surrounding your content, because the drawer and main panel have a fixed height of 100%. It works like this:

```
<paper-header-panel>
 <paper-header-panel drawer>
  Scrollable drawer panel Content
 </paper-header-panel>
 <paper-scroll-header-panel main>
  Scrollable main panel content
 </paper-scroll-header-panel>
</paper-header-panel>
```

I also suggest you remove the attribute `drawer` at the closing `</div>` tag.

Please see the documentation for more information: [paper-header-panel docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel)